# Is it possible to fade a div in slowly on mouse-over, but then fade it out quickly on mouse-out, using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

I have some j-query script that toggle fades a div upon hovering over a separate div. The div fades in at the same rate as it fades out. What I am wanting to achieve is having the div fade in slowly upon mouse-over, but then fade out very quickly upon mouse-out.

The script I have so far is as shows:

```
// JS code
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#nav1").hover(function(){
            $("#splat1").fadeToggle(2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

So currently the #splat1 div fades both in and then out again in 2 seconds. What I'd ideally like is for it to fade in over 2 seconds, but then fade out in 0.5 seconds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, replace hover with two separate events, one for mouseenter, the other for mouseout. Don't forget to use .finish() before your fadeOut.

Comment: Of course, anything is possible. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [.hover() function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) can accept two functions, one for fade in and one for fade out:

```
$("#nav1").hover(function(){
        $("#splat1").stop().fadeToggle(2000);
    },
    function(){
        $("#splat1").stop().fadeToggle(500);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yfX6/

Per the API, this is actually shorthand for the .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() function calls, which you could also use:

```
$("#nav1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#splat1").stop().fadeToggle(2000);
}).mouseleave(
    function(){
    $("#splat1").stop().fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: Worked a treat Richard, and thanks for the jsfiddle demo too :-)

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UTUr/1/)

```
$(function(){ // DOM READY shorthand

    $("#nav1").hover(function( e ){
         $("#splat1").stop().fadeToggle(e.type=="mouseenter" ? 2000 : 500);
    });

});
```

`.hover()` will listen for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events
Using a simple `Ternary Operator` you can than assign the **toggle speed** to `.fadeToggle()`

Ternary (Conditional) Operator is a shorthand for the classic IF statement and works like:

```
booleanStatement ? ifTrue : else ;
```

to visualize:

```
e.type=="mouseenter" ? TRUE : FALSE(is mouseleave) ;
```

Additionally the `.stop()` method prevents any animation buildups on fast mouseenter - mouseleave

Comment: @SamFridayWelch explore the Conditional Operator, it will help you to keep your code compact and easily maintainable (if you understand it well!) and don't forget to use `.stop()` while dealing with `.animate()`! You're welcome :)